# about menu in joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Hi everyone I am very new in joomla and i a little confuse for create the menu.

fisrt a create in the administrator site a menu of type mainmenu with categories and articles. And it is fine.

second I create a template the position in my template is this

```
<positions>
    <position>izquierdo</position>
    <position>extranet</position>
    <position>menuPrincipal</position>
    <position>carrusel</position>
    <position>noticias</position>
    <position>footer</position>
    <position>debug</position>
</positions>
```

I want my menu in this position `<position>menuPrincipal</position>`
and this is the body in the index of my template

```
<body class="cabecera <?php ($portada)? "" : "_otra"  ?> ">
        <div id="wrapper-top" class="fondo <?php ($portada)? "": "_otra" ?> ">
            <div class="row">
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="mod_izquierdo" style="none"/>
                    <div id="wrapper-header-right" class="column grid_10">
                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="mod_extranet" style="none"/>
                    <div id="Menu_Principal">
                        <ul class="menu">
                            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="mod_menuPrincipal" style="none"/>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div id="wrapper-body" class="row">
        <div id="content" class="column grid_16">
            <jdoc:include type="component" />
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="mod_noticias" style="none"/>
        </div>

        <div class="clr"></div>
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="mod_carrusel" style="none"/>
        <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="mod_pie" style="none"/>
</body>
```

this is work fine, but I don´t undestand very well

this is my menu

```
                <div id="Menu_Principal">
                    <ul class="menu">
                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="mod_menuPrincipal" style="none"/>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

I public my menu like that
Main Menu (Public in mod_menuPrincipal)

if I errase this line `<jdoc:include type="modules" name="mod_menuPrincipal" style="none"/>` don´t show me the menu, but what is the functionality of "mod_menuPrincipal" I create this module to put inside the menu, but at the end I moved the menu to my index and now this module is empty.

what is the proper performance?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to fix the code in your template. The position for your menu should look like this -

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="menuPrincipal" style="none"/>
```

Next, in the admin, find Module Manager in the Extensions menu. In the module parameters, there is a parameter that allows you to select the module position you want the module to display in. Select menuPrincipal for the menu module. Last, you want to make sure that the module is assigned to at least one menu item. You probably want it to display on All menu items though, that is an option as well.

Answer (score 2):

The

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="mod_menuPrincipal" style="none"/>
```

is a syntax to show your particular module in specific position in your template.And `mod_menuPrincipal` is a module, from where your menu code has been generated and displayed in your template position.

For more detail see this [link](http://docs.joomla.org/Module)